# Unable to authorize Amazon API Gateway using API Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-api-gateway

As per amazon's documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html) I am supposed to see a dropdown near API KEY. Although I have admin access I don't get such an option.

[image: API Gateway screenshot]

Please assist setting up authorization in API gateway using API Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like you are setting up [Mock integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html) - that doesn't support authorization. You can only enable API KEY in *real integration*, not in Mock.

Hope that helps :)